# Проблема с доступом Uri

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions

Я сериализую список с Uri (переделанного в строчку, так как Uri напрямую не сериализуется) файлов, которые выбрал пользователь. И во время выполнения программы все хорошо, файлы загружаются, при смене Activity файлы при нажатии все равно открываются, но  если я закрою программу, или выключу телефон, то во время попытки открытия файла, мне выкидывает исключение:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.schedule/com.schedule.files}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
И показывает, что данное исключение генерируется при попытке получить название файла из Uri, если точнее то в строчке:

```
Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

Вот код функции получения имени файла:

```
private String getFileName(Uri uri) {
        Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        assert returnCursor != null;
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
        returnCursor.close();
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: Храните абсолютный путь к файлу в sharedpreference, и обращайтесь через него

Answer (score 0):

При получении `Uri` нужно запросить удержание прав доступа, иначе они сбрасываются после перезагрузки системы:

```java
final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
            & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
// Check for the freshest data.
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10134 and Uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/djggfdkgf.docx [user 0]
Теперь такое исключение

Comment: Это должно работать для document-uri, полученных через SAF, для остальных никаких гарантий. И вызывать это нужно сразу при получении файла, когда права уже потерялись это делать бесполезно.